# Is it possible to update Lenovo T500 hybrid graphics driver?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon, intel-graphics

Hope someone had the same problem before. My laptop comes with two video "cards". Intel MHD4500 and ATI Radeon HD3650 (mobility). I can switch between them with the "Lenovo Battery Manager" from the taskbar. All good, but Lenovo provides the driver for this. The problem with that driver is they are a bit old. (Both Intel and ATI). For example I doubt  I have any gpu accel in flash, and I experience some problem with dual display setup, which the new ATI driver would solve.

Basically I want to create a new driver (I read a topic where a guy said its possible... baaack then when I was searching for something else). One needs a special ATI driver creation utility or what... sorry I can't recall the name of it.

Thanks in advance.

(Ah yes I forgot: The OS is a Windows 7 x64 Ultimate.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One needs a special ATI driver
>   creation utility or what... sorry I
>   can't recall the name of it.

That's no longer required, unless your laptop is a [Toshiba/Sony/Panasonic](http://www.worldtech24.com/windows/ati-adds-laptop-support-catalyst-103-drivers) - but luckily, yours isn't. Grab the HD3640 drivers from [here](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonmob_win7-64.aspx).

Grab the Intel HD4500 drivers from [here](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Laptop+graphics+controllers&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+HD+Graphics&ProdId=3231&LineId=1101&FamilyId=39).

Comment: Okay, I always hated ATI: http://noob.hu/2010/06/12/wtf.jpg ... "Tell me whyyyy...." :) | (It just downloads a ~1.5mb package instead of the ~70mb one, unpacks it into C:\... and this comes up.)

Comment: Wrote the question on Lenovo Community + ThinkPads forums. Hope someone will come up with a solution. Anyway, kudos for you, its already a help. (And any help are still welcome!!!!111)

Comment: @shiki still got the problem ?

Comment: Of course. :( No one answered my question on the other sites. Lenovo got only phone support but I have a feeling they would simply say switch to permanent "Discrete graphics" (ATI) and that's it. However, sometimes I have to use it from battery, and ATI sucks. My battery. :)

Comment: @Shiki Hm, sorry - I don't have a Lenovo or an ATi so can't help you much. Let me see if I can get something more

Comment: @Sathya: Thank you very much for all the help and any info/idea are welcome.

Comment: @Shiki Do the newer Catalyst drivers help at all ?

Comment: @Sathya - Yes it does. Now I turned off the switchable stuff, and now I've got only an ATI HD 3650. Installed the latest drivers from ATI and it works like a charm. :(